# Why is AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh's picture so dark?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video-capture, avcapturesession, image-quality

Playing around with `AVCapureSessions` and trying to display the output `CMSampleBufferRef`'s in different ways (using a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, displaying a `CGImage` and transforming it to a `UIImage`), I also looked at all the different quality presets you can set for you `AVCaptureSession`.

Then I noticed how the quality differences between

- `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow`,
- `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium` and
- `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`

are not only the resolution of the image but also their aspect ratio and most notably the overall image quality. In my specific case, frames gotten with `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow/Medium` were much brighter than those with `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`. Why is this?

To set up the session and to display the images I used this code: http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera

To set the presets:

```
[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
```

Here two examples with `Medium` and `High` quality:

[image: AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]
[image: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]

I assure you that these two screenshots are made pointing the camera at the same spot, same time and with the same light conditions.

Comment: have you got the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is caused by the purpose of those presets. While `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` is basically for making video, `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow/Medium` might be used for creating photos as well because they have the same behavior as `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` preset. You can try your default camera app.